# Give width to th element doesn't work for me

Tags: html, css

I have this [table](http://jsfiddle.net/xBsxH/), and I want to give a width to a th element, but it doesn't work..

```
     <th style="width: 400px">
        Room type                                    
     </th>
```

Any help?

Comment: maybe your table is too short to give width to the th..

Comment: Although it's good to post a jsfiddle, you probably shouldn't rely on users being able to view it in order to understand your question.

Answer (score 3):

It does work, it's just that there's no room for the `th` to get `300px` width, use `min-width` instead

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/xBsxH/1/)

[Another Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xBsxH/2/)

Comment: Yes. A table will by default scale the columns to fit the contents. You can work around this using `min-width`, or by using [`table-layout: fixed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/table-layout) on the table element itself.

Comment: @Mr.Alien, thanks, now I'm trying to give a with to the second column head using also `min-with` but it doesn't work..

Answer (score 0):

use `min-width` instead of `width`

Answer (score 0):

your table is too short to give width to the th..
delete some columns or just enlarge your table width.
like:

```
<table width="2000px">
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `min-width`, `display: inline-block;` or `display: block;`.

I think the first is the best...

Answer (score 0):

Due to your table being wide the **width** tag is not sufficient, use **min-width** instead.

```
<th style="min-width: 300px;" />
```

I would also recommend using colgroups if you are planning on setting a number of different widths in your headers - makes it easier to maintain and keeps it in one place.